# Outlook 2010, Recipients do not get the Follow Up Reminder in their email message

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

Whenever I send emails with a Follow up and Reminder to the recipients they  receive the email but without showing the Flag and the reminder to them.

How can this be resolved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kindly see following steps or visit [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Flag-an-item-for-follow-up-7b0f0c0e-21a6-41f0-96de-2cbda41e7eb1) link.

**Add a flag for recipients**

If you want to encourage people to reply to a message or you want to request other actions from them, you can send them a flagged message. You can add text that is specific to your request. You can choose from several options in a list or type your own text. The default text is Follow Up.

- In a new message, on the Message tab, in the Tags group, click Follow Up.
- On the Follow Up menu, click Flag for Recipients.
- In the Flag to list, select an action, or type your own text. What you select or type here appears in the InfoBar in the message that the recipient receives.
- If you do not want to send a reminder with the message, clear the Reminder box.
- If you want to send a reminder with the message, in the Flag for Recipients section, select a date and time from the lists. If you do not want to send a reminder, clear the Reminder box.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response! However, the issue I raised is that after I perform all the steps that you mentioned above the recipients of the email do not see the Flags and the reminder when this kind of email reaches their Inbox.

Comment: Click the Follow Up on the Message tab and click; Custom…-> enable: Flag for Recipients